# 404 error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, http-status-code-404, tomcat6

http://localhost:8081/

HTTP Status 404 - /

---

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource (/) is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.32

in eclipse to start the server then server is started but i open the tomacat home page then show above error 
please help.. me....

Comment: Are you sure your tomcat is running on port 8081? Normally its on 8080.

Comment: yes,i am running port number is 8081....

Comment: On startup does it shoes any error in console output? Are you doing any kinda operation on server startup which can cause server startup fail?

Comment: please help me Harry Joy.....

Comment: @najeer: With the limited information you have provided its hard to tell the solution. Provide more information. Are you able access your project's url?

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/Webservice/article.html#wssimple

Comment: The url is itself a tutorial. Have you followed all the steps correctly? or make change in any steps listed on site?

Comment: followed the all the steps correctly.. only modification is port number is change in tomcat installation

Comment: Can you show your server.xml where you changed the port? Have you ever run it successfully with 8080?

Comment: <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: @harry - he's getting a 404 from Tomcat so must be running on that port, it's just his app has failed to start or is under some context

Answer (score 1):

Given you're getting a 404 I'd hazard a guess you are indeed running on port 8081. So the message is what it says: the resource is not available. Tomcat applications often run with a "context" to separate them from other apps running in the same container. The context is just a path like `/myapp` or something. This should be configured in your web.xml.

So having checked the context is "/" do you actually have a file/resource bound to the root like an index page?

And last suggestion is: what's been printed out to the eclipse console? Any Exceptions? If the webapp did not start properly you will get a "resource not found"